# Clock announcing time when it shouldn't

Tags: macos, text-to-speech, clock

Years ago, I turned on "announce time on the hour," but when it turned out to be stupid (for US locale, instead of "Ten o'clock" it says "it's ten hours") I turned it off.

Three days ago, when I wasn't even near the laptop, it started announcing time again.  I knew I hadn't changed it, but I looked and it was still Unchecked.  There have been no recent updates to the system to explain the change in behavior.

I tried turning it on and back off, but it continues to announce.  Before I turned it off again, I also changed "on the hour" to "every quarter hour" but it is still only doing it on the hour (when it shouldn't do it at all).

Why? and How to fix?

I moved `Library/Preferences/com.apple.menuextra.clock.plist` to /tmp but that changed nothing (and changing the setting did not recreate it).  I opened that file in Xcode, and it contains only two of the eight time preferences.

Comment: What is the version of macOS that you are running? It's very well possible that it's simply a bug in macOS.

Comment: Latest version.  Reported as a bug; no doubt two weeks from now, they'll ask me to send a sysdiagnose "as close as possible to the time of the event."

Answer (score 0):

I am here because I'm looking for a way to make my OS X Leopard (2011 iMac) stop announcing the time; after unchecking it in all existing users' Date & Time preferences and rebooting it's still doing it hourly. I cannot yet state a fix for the problem, but I can contribute the location of a relevant plist:

~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs.plist

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/344335)

Comment: IconDaemon: I stated that I haven't (yet) got a fix. Neither has anyone else, and I spent a lot of time looking. But the question mentioned a search for the relevant plist, and I was able to provide that. I considered doing it in a comment, but my impression from reading hundreds of other posts in the last few years is that my contribution was more appropriately placed as a solution.